# Install macOS on external SSD

Tags: macos, ssd, big-sur, ventura

Can I install macOS to an external SSD and use it to restore macs? I can't seem to get it to install, keep erroring when trying to install it. Any help?

Comment: You should be able to install macOS to an external SSD. Do you have a full installer? Which version of macOS are you using and which version are you installing? What is the model/year of your Mac? What mode is your SSD?

Comment: I used mds to make the installer, made a 4 partition os installer. Got a 2015 macbook air…ssd in apsf guid

Comment: What does mds stand for?

Comment: Mac deploy stick, check out the site twocanoes.com